# JS event listener for a type of element?

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

Is there a way to add some kind of listener for a type of html element? For example if i wanna call a function when the user clicks **any** p element

Comment: You could attach the event itself to the `body` element and then check for the type of the event target.

Comment: "want to", not "wanna"

Answer (score 4):

the easiest answer would be using `addEventListener()` if you want a specific html tag just like what i wanted in [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44730431/can-i-in-javascript-write-an-event-or-a-function-that-automatically-applies-to) then you'll find the answer there ill paraphrase it here too
add this

```html
<script>
    document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
   //your desired nodeName like : DIV , SPAN , LI etc
       if(e.target && e.target.nodeName== 'DIV')
       //add a function below to trigger 
       {alert('bingo')}
    });

</script>
```

to the end of your document
by the way don't forget to use uppercase nodeNames or just put a `toLowerCase()` before it. cheers :)

Answer (score 3):

Add the event listener to the `window` / `document` / `document.body` and check the type of the element **and the types of its parents** because if you have a `<span>` inside a `<p>`, clicking the span won't trigger the click in the paragraph.

```
document.addEventListener("click", function (eventArgs) {
    var target = eventArgs.target;
    var elementToLookFor = "p";
    while (target !== null) {
        if (target.tagName.toLowerCase() === elementToLookFor) {
            // Do magic stuff with the paragraph
            console.log(target);
        }
        target = target.parentElement;
    }
});
```

This technique is called "event delegation."

**Edit:** Note that you cannot early return from the loop above. If your have nested paragraphs, i.e.

```
<p>
    Hey,
    <p>there!</p>
</p>
```

Having an early return will only call your event handler for the inner paragraph, whereas you said that you'd like the handler to be invoked on **every** paragraph which is why you need to traverse all the ancestors of the element.

Comment: Typcially these go on `document` (or less-commonly `document.body`), not `window`. (I'm a bit surprised it works on `window`.)

Comment: I would upvote if you change the listener to be on the `document` object.  You can also `break` out of the `while` loop when you find a matching `tagName`.  No need to keep looking.

Comment: @jfriend00 Early return will not be a proper answer to this question as I mentioned in the answer but I just edited it to make it more clear. Regarding your first critique, it doesn't really matter on which object the event is hooked, but I guess you are right that the `document` node might be better from a stylistic / semantic point of view. See the edit.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are looking for code along these lines:

```
var paras = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

// Loop through elements. 
for(var i = 0; i < paras.length; i++) {
    // Add listener.
    paras[i].addEventListener("click",
        function() { 
            // Execute function.
        }, false);
}
```

Comment: **Much** better to use event delegation as in [Nikola's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31227823/157247) than to individually hook `click` on every `p` element, not least because it lets you add and remove `p` elements without worrying about hooking up their `click`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just select all the elements on the page and add eventListeners on them like so:

```
function addListeners(elementType, eventType, callback) {
    Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(elementType)).forEach(function (el, i) {
        el.addEventListener(eventType, callback, false);
    });
}
```

Above we use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to pick all the wanted elements, convert it to an Array (if you use es6, you can use [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)) and then we loop through the array and add listeners with the wanted callback.

Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/a7en4d4s/

Answer (score -1):

Look at this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nv6n6axq/1/), and see if it works for you

```
<span>Click Yes</span><br/><br/>
<span>Click No</span><br/><br/>
<a>Clicked: <b id="result"></b></a>
<script>
    $("span").click(function(){
    var a = $(this).html();
    $("#result").html(a);
    });
</script>
```