# Can i (in javascript) write an event or a function that automatically applies to one kind of html tag?

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener, event-delegation

I was looking for a way to apply an `onclick();` or a function  to all the `<span></span>` tags in my page, even the ones which are created later, like a universal order for all of this type of html tag.

despite of ID class type or any other attribute only tag name.

Edit: Answered by @mhodges by introducing [this](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate)

note that you should use `toLowerCase()` too

Comment: Add a listener to `document.body` and check for the tag type on a click.

Comment: Search the term [`event delegation`](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate)

Comment: That's the phrase I was searching my brain for and was escaping me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Put a class in them, and then when you use an `onclick`, you search them with `$(".classname")`

Comment: no i need all spans , as i said despite of their attributes to be effected

Comment: Check this  [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/nv6n6axq/1/) , hope it helps

Comment: actually [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) worked just fine for me , that's a cool method too, thanks, maybe ill use the code for changing the `innerHTML` in my project :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know plain javascript or is jQuery also allowed?

```
$('body').on('click', 'span', function() {

});
```

Here a small example

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  let i = 1;
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    i++;
    $('#wrapper').append('<span> ' + i + ' </span>');
  });
  
  $('#wrapper').on('click', 'span', function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <span>1</span>
</div>

<button>Add</button>
```

Comment: `... even the ones which are created later`

Comment: this will not work for the `span` tags created/added later into the DOM

Comment: Updated my answer, have a look now, this will also work with dynamic added spans. Wrapper around your span instead of body would be not bad

Comment: Doesn't work without jQuery.

Comment: i dont know any jQuery but if its possible in plain javascript it would be fantastic

Comment: @AminHamidi Check the article I linked to below your question - that implements this answer in plain JS

Comment: @mhodges im working on it to see if it works on my project :)

Comment: It will work. :)

Comment: im sure it will work its seems right but dunno where am i wrong in it , surely i will figure it out until the morning , now would you put that link as an answer so i would check that correct answer oprtion for you @mhodges ;)

Comment: `document.getElementById("body").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        // e.target is the clicked element!
        // If it was a list item
        if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "span") {alert('boom')
        }
    })`  @mhodges isnt this supposed to work

Comment: @AminHamidi Does your outer-most container have an id of body? If not, use `document.querySelector("body")` instead. or even more simply, `document.addEventListener(...)`

Comment: @mhodges everything works fine untill it becomes to event and e.target . tried changing body id and container div , no results so far

Comment: i mean the following piece of code     `document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
        if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == 'span'){alert('bingo')}
    });`  is supposed to add a listener to all the document and whenever the case matches the alert goes on, but i guess there should be a problem with the event i had the same problem with my project that needed getting mouse X , Y coordinates

Comment: coding and this uppercase problems XD omg , i should've used SPAN or DIV because the system turn them to upper case , thanks @mhodges problem solved